# Android - Access a SMB folder in a app that doesn't support this

Tags: android, networking, directory, smb, cifs

I have Retroarch installed on my Android box.
I want to access my ROMs from a network folder on my Windows computer.
Tried to create an SMB share with cifs but the folder isn't visible inside Retroarch.

Maybe if I build a top layer app, and this app creates an SMD share and then call Retroarch. If Retroarch runs in the same context as top layer app, it will be able to access the shared SMB folder?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for SMB on Android. I only know of one app called LAN drive, but you have to open the ports on your computer because Android doesn't support ports that low natively, there's the big limitation, I hope Android 12 or 13 will fix this, I've been testing and it's extremely useful for college or programming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).